# batch preparedstatement with different sql queries

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, sql-injection, batch-processing

I found existing questions [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366547/preparedstatement-batching-with-different-sql-statements) to this one that did not actually have a clear answer to the question.

A normal batch preparedstatement with one sql query would look something like this:

```
private static void batchInsertRecordsIntoTable() throws SQLException {

        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
                + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
                + "(?,?,?,?)";

        try {
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

            dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 101);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "mkyong101");
            preparedStatement.setString(3, "system");
            preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());
            preparedStatement.addBatch();

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 102);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "mkyong102");
            preparedStatement.setString(3, "system");
            preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());
            preparedStatement.addBatch();

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 103);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "mkyong103");
            preparedStatement.setString(3, "system");
            preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());
            preparedStatement.addBatch();

            preparedStatement.executeBatch();

            dbConnection.commit();

            System.out.println("Record is inserted into DBUSER table!");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            dbConnection.rollback();

        } finally {

            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }

            if (dbConnection != null) {
                dbConnection.close();
            }

        }

    }
```

*Taken from: http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/*

However, I'm looking for a way to perform batch transactions on **different** sql queries. i.e. `INSERT INTO TABLE A` and `INSERT INTO TABLE B` without the risk of SQL Injection attacks. I know that preparedstatements are the preferred method of avoiding such attacks but I don't know of a way to do batch transactions on differentiating SQL queries?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For two (2) different SQL queries you will need two (2) different `PreparedStatement` objects and each one will have its own batch, but you can simply execute each batch when you want to send the queries to the server:

```java
try (
        PreparedStatement thisPs = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO thisTable (thisId, thisText) VALUES (?,?)");
        PreparedStatement thatPs = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO thatTable (thatId, thatText) VALUES (?,?)")) {

    thisPs.setInt(1, 1);
    thisPs.setString(2, "thisText1");
    thisPs.addBatch();

    thatPs.setInt(1, 1);
    thatPs.setString(2, "thatText1");
    thatPs.addBatch();

    thisPs.setInt(1, 2);
    thisPs.setString(2, "thisText2");
    thisPs.addBatch();

    thatPs.setInt(1, 2);
    thatPs.setString(2, "thatText2");
    thatPs.addBatch();

    thisPs.executeBatch();
    thatPs.executeBatch();
}
```

Also, be aware of terminology. Talking about a "batch transaction" is somewhat ambiguous:

- `addBatch` and `executeBatch` are part of the mechanism to send multiple statements to the server as a single **batch** (transmission). This affects the way the statements are *sent (transmitted) to* the database server.
- A database **transaction** is the mechanism whereby a number of statements will be processed as a complete group, i.e., either the *whole* group will be processed ("committed") or the *whole* group will be discarded ("rolled back"). The `Connection#setAutoCommit()`, `Connection#commit()`, and `Connection#rollback()` methods control this behaviour.  This affects the way the statements are *executed by* the database server.

Comment: I know that multiple instances can be created but if all the queries are different then this will add no performance benefit at all. I ended up just foregoing the SQL Injection safety and using a regular batch statement instead of preparedstatements.

Comment: This can have a performance benefit.  2 batches is better than no batches (assuming here is more than 1 row per batch), but could have problems with data dependencies.   E.g. there can be no foreign key dependencies in the 1st batch on rows that will be inserted in the 2nd batch.  In a normal parent/child table use case, this approach will work fine, so long as you execute the parent table batch first.

Comment: @Hooli: **foregoing the SQL Injection safety** at the cost of performance is not good if input is really coming from unsafe places like UI, though you are better judge for your system.