# Statement - Connection.setAutoCommit(false);

Tags: java, jdbc

If I have a Connection con open and a Statment stat what does the `stat.executeBatch()`?

I think it does nothing because I have set autocommit to false.

Here an example:

```
stat.addBatch("update bankaccount set balance = balance + 100 where customer = 'Bill'");
stat.addBatch("update bankaccount set balance = balance - 100 where customer = 'Joe'");
stat.executeBatch();
con.commit();
```

Comment: If you're doing batching, you *need* to set autocommit to false.

Comment: but why i need then executeBatch? What does it?

Comment: You're adding stuff to a batch with `addBatch`, and then executing that batch with `executeBatch`. Your `autocommit` has nothing to do with it. (That's to do with having to `commit` at the end.)

Comment: Then I do not need a commit at the end?

Comment: You need the `commit()` because you set `autocommit` to false.

Comment: but with execute it is already at the database? Whats the difference to commit?

Comment: If you're doing batching, the common idiom is to come up with a suitable batch size N (such as 100), and execute the batch every N rows. Finally you commit the transaction after all the batches have been executed. If you don't understand what `commit()` (and therefore autocommit) does, I suggest you read about it before you move on.

Comment: @thomas Go and read about [database transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction).

Comment: you mean, that it is at the database but i can only read it with isolation level read_uncommited? :-)
with commit I get the usual result (read_commited)

Comment: If the database supports read uncommitted, then at least in theory yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [batch preparedstatement with different sql queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041410/batch-preparedstatement-with-different-sql-queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch Processing allows you to group related SQL statements into a batch and submit them with one call to the database.

When you send several SQL statements to the database at once, you reduce the amount of communication overhead, thereby improving performance.

- The **addBatch()** method of *Statement*, *PreparedStatement*, and *CallableStatement* is used to add individual statements to the batch.
- The **executeBatch()** is used to start the execution of all the statements grouped together.

Also,

To enable manual- transaction support instead of the auto-commit mode that the JDBC driver uses by default, use the Connection object's **setAutoCommit()** method.

If you pass a boolean false to setAutoCommit( ), you turn off auto-commit. You can pass a boolean true to turn it back on again.